# Binary Tree in java Jung Graph package

Tags: java, binary-tree, jung

I am trying to create binary trees in JUNG (a graph package for Java). However, I cannot get manage to accomplish this.

Here is my source:

```
Tree tree1 = new OrderedKAryTree<String, Integer>(2);
tree1.addVertex("v0");
tree1.addEdge(1, "v0", "v1");
tree1.addEdge(2, "v0", "v2");
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'index' must be in [0, [order-1]]
```

In the [documentation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/OrderedKAryTree.html), I see one of the overloaded methods `addEdge()` takes an integer parameter called index as the 4th argument. However, there appears to be no implementation of that on my machine.

This should create a binary tree of height 1. I've tried adding vertices before edges as well:

```
tree1.addVertex("v0");
tree1.addVertex("v1");
tree1.addVertex("v2");
tree1.addEdge(1, "v0", "v1");
tree1.addEdge(2, "v0", "v2");
```

Here is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
    Unless you are setting the root, use addEdge() or addChild()
```

The weird part is, there is no `addChild()` method in the [documentation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/package-summary.html) (I assuming `addChild()` was part of an older version of the package and was not removed in the latest update)

Creating a small binary tree should not be hard! Can someone help?

Comment: I'm trying to build something similar and I'm curious if you were ever able to find a workaround or did you go with some other library?

Answer (score 1):

for tree you need to use setRoot and addChild function

---

```
    DelegateTree<String, String> tree = new DelegateTree<String,String>();
    tree.setRoot("A");
    tree.addChild("A-B1", "A", "B1");
    tree.addChild("A-B2", "A", "B2");

    BasicVisualizationServer<String, String> vs = new BasicVisualizationServer<String, String>(
            new FRLayout<String,String>(tree), new Dimension(1100, 640));


     Transformer<String,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<String,Paint>() {
            public Paint transform(String i) {
                return Color.GRAY;
            }
        };  



        RenderContext<String, String> renderContext = vs.getRenderContext();
                renderContext.setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);

            Transformer<String, String> transformer = new ToStringLabeller<String>();
            renderContext.setEdgeLabelTransformer(transformer);
            Transformer<String, String> vertexTransformer = new ToStringLabeller<String>();
            renderContext.setVertexLabelTransformer(vertexTransformer);
            vs.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);



            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.getContentPane().add(vs);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several [errors](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CANYy1UnP7mZ35VtO0666m%3DpOEYC0vM%2B2BrCOujoJ3%2BYatTBKXA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=jung-support) in that class and I don't think a lot of development is still going on. You could try fixing it for your own purposes in a local build (you can find the source code on the website) and maybe even commiting them to the community.

Comment: There is still development going on over on Google Code: http://jung.googlecode.com  That said, this code does have at least one bug (and at least one doc error) and does need to be fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear there's still development. I just thought the project was on hold as the last commit was in April.

Comment: Your conclusion was not unreasonable given the evidence.  Stuff is going on under the hood that hasn't been committed yet.  :)